# Inherit border-radius from child to parent

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm working on a React Component that acts as a clickable wrapper for other components and the issue I have is that some of the other components have a border-radius which makes the wrapper component stick out in the corners. How I've solved this is by giving the wrapper the same border-radius via a prop, the problem with this approach is that I don't know the border-radius of some components. I've been trying to find a way to get the border-radius attribute value from the child component by using `useRef()` and then `wrapperRef.current.props.children[0]` but the border-radius value isn't present.

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.demo-wrapper {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 24px;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.child {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 24px;
  background-color: teal;
  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>What i get</p>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="child"><p>child element</p></div>
  </div>
  <p>What i want</p>
  <div class="demo-wrapper">
    <div class="child"><p>child element</p></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to get the border-radius value from the child element?
Or is there a way to inherit the border-radius from child to parent element?
Or maybe I'm going on about this in the wrong direction entirely and there is a better way to solve this other than setting the same border-radius on parent element?

Answer (score 1):

This solution involves:

1. Setting a `ref` on the wrapper element
2. Using `useEffect`, which runs *after* the component's rendered:

   2.1. Use `element.firstChild` on the wrapper `ref`, to get a reference to the child's outer html element

   2.2 Use `getComputedStyle()` to get the child element's border radius

   2.3 Set that border radius on the wrapper element, using our ref.

The wrapper then would be:

```
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

const Wrapper = ({ children }) => {
  const container = useRef();

  useEffect(()=>{
    const borderRadius = getComputedStyle(container.current.firstChild).borderRadius
    container.current.style.borderRadius = borderRadius
  }, [])

  return <div ref={container}>{children}</div>;
};
```

A working example:

[image: Edit old-wave-ypyqk1]